# What programming language to be used for developing sofware for Mobile Phones?

Tags: mobile-phones, programming-languages

What language should I use to develop programs for Nokia/Samsung/LG/Sony Ericsson phones? (Both Symbian and Non Symbian) ?

Ofcourse to install the software straight inside the phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 main "classes" of applications for mobile phones - native apps and Java apps.

For Java, most new phones support some version of [MIDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Information_Device_Profile), and developing for it is fairly easy. As for installation, however, it's a little more tricky. In general you install applications through links on the internet, but some carriers put limits on which applications can be installed on your phone.

For native apps, it depends on the OS of your phone. For most of them, developing native applications costs a lot of money (for tools and SDKs) and there are also issues with how the applications are distributed. Installation and debugging are, again, different depending on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

java (j2me) is currently the de-facto language.. but probably not for long!

[See the mobile sun website](http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp)

Comment: You mean we can use C# to develop softwares for phones like Nokia?

Comment: No,not yet.C# is MS platform compatible right now,but the Mono project might change that in future.

Comment: The reason I said "probably not for long.." is that some bigger players are taking note of the uptake of ODP etc. which will envitably lead to MS to invest even more heavily in their Windows Mobile platform! MIDP will be around for a long time to come though.. hopefully!

Comment: I don't agree that it wont be there for long. T-Mobile has sold over 1 million G1 phones in the first six months. Analysts expect that sales will go up a 900 percent (!) this year, with IPhone on the second place at 75%. Since Android development is oriented around java, it will still be the de-facto language.

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung i7500 is powered by Android and many seems to jump onto that same train. Android is the shit :) Basically java but compiled into Dalvik executable (.dex format). You develop in e.g. Ellipse.